# Errors updating Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to update Anaconda, but I'm getting errors and I don't know what they mean.

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==2019.07=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::numba==0.44.1=py37hf9181ef_0
```

Does anyone have a clue what this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
conda install anaconda
```